# Building Raspberry Pi apps from Windows

Tags: raspbian, windows, opencv, c++

I want to build a C++ program for face detection using Visual Studio and OpenCV.

I already installed the Visual Studio 2013 Express Edition and the OpenCV 2.4.8 on my Windows 8 computer and linked the libraries of the OpenCV and it's working.

Now I want to know what do I need to compile any program I build on the Raspberry Pi (raspbin),
knowing that my Raspberry Pi SD card is working.

I found [this tutorial](http://gnutoolchains.com/raspberry/tutorial/), but I don't want to change the things installed on the SD card.

Comment: You want to compile binaries that are run on arm-hf or use MONO to run EXE's? Doing the binary compilation is very difficult on Windows, because you need to set up a cross compile environment, include source files and header from any libraries you are using, etc, into ARM architecture on a x86 compiler.

Answer (score 2):

MONO doesn't run a file with third party libraries like opencv .I just udated my c++ file using cross compiling (MinGW) on eclipse to be able to run it on linux and I compile the .cpp file on the pi.

Comment: Still, it's not that way. Note that `MinGW` will produce **Windows** **Intel** binaries. The simples way is to compile from Raspberry Pi, or installing Linux on PC and setting up cross-compiler.